# create .htaccess file by using php mysql.

Tags: php, mysql, html, .htaccess

i have a website of news articles. in this, when i click any article then it's address is look like news.php?id=12 but i want that it look like http://paritynews.com/news/YYYY/MM/DD/<4-digit number>/headline/. 
in this first show the news category then date of article post then article number and in last it show the headline of the post.
here id link http://www.monkks.com/part/parity-newsfinalpage/index.php
thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a nice post to for using custom URL. 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

You can use RewriteRule to generate your required type of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess file and the $_REQUEST variable.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This is the index.php file. I have added comments where you have to actually run the query and deal with the results.

```
//Routing...
$request = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1); //Out of the http://www.domain.com/blog/date -> blog/date is returned
$params  = explode("/", $request); //Creates an array $params = ['blog','date'];

if($params[0] == ""){
//Default Route
    $include_path = "default.html";
}else{
//If there is something in the URL that is useful
//Parse the rest of the url here
switch ($params[0]) {//The first varible Ex: 'blog' or 'news'
    case 'news':
        $article_date = join(array($params[1],$params[2],$params[3]),"-");//Formats the date for MySQL
        $id_number = $params[4];
        //Make sure to escpe the values here
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (date_column = {$article_date} AND id = {$id_number}";
        //Run the query with your perfered sql extension, mysqli or pdo
        //Handle errors
        $include_path = "news.php";
    break;
    case 'other':
        $include_path = "something_else.php";
        break;
    }
}
if(isset($include_path)){
    require($include_path);
}
?>
```

Comment: thnks. but i really don't have a good knowledge about this. so please can you explain it. please.